# svn list of files that are modified in local copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use Tortoise client to checkout/commit my changes to SVN. But I found this little difficult because I'm not able to find List of all files that are changed in my local copy. Is there any short cut or something that I overlooked?

I'm new to SVN. FYI.

Comment: Maybe a mod can clean this thread up, there are like 10 posts here containing the same answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The "Check for Modifications" command in tortoise will display a list of all changed files in the working copy. "Commit" will show all changed files as well (that you can then commit). "Revert" will also show changed files (that you can then revert).

Comment: Ah! I missed to try "check for modifications"

Comment: TIL Tortoise had a "check for modifications" function :) Many thanks.

Answer (score 124):

I'm not familiar with tortoise, but with subversion to linux i would type

```
svn status
```

Some googling tells me that tortoise also supports commandline commandos, try svn status in the folder that contains the svn repository.

Comment: The Windows command line client has the same command, so you can use this if you are even using cmd.

Comment: To show *only* the modified files in the directory: svn status -q

Comment: @BrokenLink svn installation contains all the binaries you want to have. Don't always go for UI. It will be painful and time consuming

Comment: @sarat, "It will be painful and time consuming," amen! For some things I use the graphical client (Tortoise SVN), but for things like reporting, the CLI is far better, because it's so much easier to capture the report and send it to somebody for review.

Answer (score 45):

I couldn't get `svn status -q` to work. Assuming you are on a linux box, to see only the files that are modified, run: `svn status | grep 'M   '`
On windows I am not sure what you would do, maybe something with 'FindStr'

Comment: `svn st | grep ^M` is shorter still :)

Comment: `svn st|grep ^M` is even shorter still, but it's not how I'd answer any question on Stackoverflow unless the question was specifically about code golf. @DavidRivers has the best answer.

Answer (score 10):

Below command will display the modfied files alone in windows.

```
svn status | findstr "^M"
```

Comment: In windows I used powershell ad did this `svn status | Where-Object {$_.StartsWith("M")}`

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to list **modified files only** you can reduce the output of *svn st* by leading "M" that indicates a file has been modified. I would do this like that:

```
svn st | grep ^M
```

Answer (score 6):

`svn status | grep 'M '` works fine on *MacOSX*.

I just tested this.

Comment: From the command line this is my get-go solution. But the OP asked for a solution in TortoiseSVN.

Comment: This only shows the files changed but not the changes in the files

Comment: Btw this is a duplicate answer, the same has been posted by  nils in 2014.

Comment: or `svn status | grep ^M`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the filenames and also want any files that have been added (A).

```
svn st | grep ^[AM] | cut -c9-
```

Note: The first 7 columns are each one character wide followed by a space then the filename.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it in Windows: 
svn stat | find "M"

Answer (score 0):

svn status | grep ^M will list files which are modified. 
M - stands for modified  :)

Answer (score 0):

As said you have to use `SVN Check for modification` in GUI and `tortoiseproc.exe /command:repostatus /path:"<path-to-version-control-file-or-directory>"` in CLI to see changes related to the root of the `<path-to-version-control-file-or-directory>`.

Sadly, but this command won't show *ALL* local changes, it does show only those changes which are related to the requested directory root. The changes taken separately, like standalone checkouts or orphan external directories in the root subdirectory will be shown as *Unversioned* or *Nested* and you might miss to commit/lookup them.

To avoid such condition you have to either call to `tortoiseproc.exe /command:repostatus /pathfile:"<path-to-file-with-list-of-items-to-lookup-from>"` (see detailed documentation on the command line: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), or use some 3dparty applications/utilities/scripts to wrap the call.

I has been wrote my own set of scripts **for Windows** to automate the call from the `Total Commander`:

https://github.com/andry81/tacklebar/tree/HEAD/src/scripts/scm/tortoisesvn (`tortoiseproc_by_nested_wc.bat`)

https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Scripts/Tools/ToolAdaptors/vbs (`call_nowindow.vbs`)

**- Opens TortoiseSVN status dialog for a set of WC directories (always opens to show unversioned changes).**

```
Command:   call_nowindow.vbs
Arguments: tortoisesvn\TortoiseProcByNestedWC.bat /command:repostatus "%P" %S
```

**- Opens TortoiseSVN commit dialogs for a set of WC directories (opens only if has not empty versioned changes).**

```
Command:   call_nowindow.vbs
Arguments: tortoisesvn\TortoiseProcByNestedWC.bat /command:commit "%P" %S
```

See the `README_EN.txt` for the latest details (you have to execute the `configure.bat` before the usage and copy rest of scripts on yourself like `call_nowindow.vbs`).

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell you can do this:

```
# Checks for updates and changes in working copy.
# Regex: Excludes unmodified (first 7 columns blank). To exclude more add criteria to negative look ahead.
# -u: svn gets updates
$regex = '^(?!\s{7}).{7}\s+(.+)';
svn status -u | %{ if($_ -match $regex){ $_ } };
```

This will include property changes. These show in column 2. It will also catch other differences in files that show in columns 3-7.

Sources:

- svn status: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html
- Regex to match results of svn status: [Using powershell and svn to delete unversioned files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082706/using-powershell-and-svn-to-delete-unversioned-files)

Answer (score -1):

Right click folder -> Click Tortoise SVN -> Check for modification

Comment: This has already been posted and is just copied from the already accepted answer